# Window Manager API dont work on 64bit Apps. What to use instead?

Tags: macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, macos-carbon

Apples 64 bit documentation says,
The Window Manager is not available to 64-bit applications. For information about using windows in a Cocoa user interface, see [Window Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/WinPanel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000031i).

I am not using cocoa so Window Programming Guide is no good for me. I need to use API like HIWindowGetBounds() so that I can get the window position with a coordinate space defined by the screen size in pixels. Or any other way to fetch the window position on screen?

Thank you

Comment: (a) what version of Mac OS X, (b) are you sure your developer docs are up to date, (c) why not just build your app as 32 bit ?

Comment: I am using Mac 10.6.7. Yes all docs are updated and I need to support both 32 bit and 64 bit platform and keep code portable.

Comment: I second Paul's comment c). Just build it in 32 bit mode, which runs OK on 64 bit machines too, for the time being.

Comment: Its actually injection code. I cannot change architecture of application I am injecting in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to support both 32 bit and 64 bit platform and keep code portable.

You cannot.

Carbon is dead. It will never be extended to be 64-bit. It has been dead for years now.

Cocoa is the *only* option you have.

I'm sorry.